# In a WinForm process, how to detect when a command line child process is demanding input?

Tags: c#, winforms, command-line, stdout, io-redirection

In a WinForm application that calls a third-party command line tool, there may be a time when the tool is expecting user input, such as asking if it should overwrite a file:

```
printf("%s already exists, overwrite?: <Y>es, <N>o, <A>ll, <Q>uit?",FName);
for ( ; ; )
    switch ( toupper(getch()) ) {
        case 'A':
            YesToAll=true;
        case '\r': 
        case 'Y':
            remove(FName);
            return true;
        case 0x1B: 
        case 'Q':
            printf("quit\n"); exit(-1);
        case 'N':                       
            return false;
    }
```

When that happens, I want to display the message from `printf()` and the options in a dialog box, and redirect the button click as input to the process. It probably involves using `System.Diagnostics.Process.StandardInput` to send the input. But without knowing when exactly the tool will be expecting input, I would have no idea when to react accordingly in the GUI. When the process is in this for-loop, my WinForm process will just freeze.

**EDIT**: Here's the code that unblocks the UI by starting the process in another thread, however I still could not read the output, if the file I select will cause the tool to ask overwriting options. `proc_OutputDataReceived` (**EDIT2**: or `readStdOut` in `proc.StandardOutput.BaseStream.BeginRead`'s case) will never be called , unless the tool does not ask for input).

```
    private BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    private void fileChosenHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = sender as OpenFileDialog;
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(dialog.FileName);
    }

    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string exePath = @"F:\test\test.exe";
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = exePath; 
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + (string)e.Argument + "\""; 
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(proc_OutputDataReceived);

        proc.Start();

        // method 1: read lines
        //proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        // method 2: read characters
        proc.StandardOutput.BaseStream.BeginRead(stdOutBuffer, 0, stdOutBuffer.Length, readStdOut, proc);

        proc.WaitForExit();

    }

    private void proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Output: " + e.Data);
    }

    private byte[] stdOutBuffer = new byte[20]; 

    private void readStdOut(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        Process proc = result.AsyncState as Process;

        int bytesNumber = proc.StandardOutput.BaseStream.EndRead(result);
        if (bytesNumber != 0)
        {
            string text = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stdOutBuffer, 0, bytesNumber);
            MessageBox.Show("Output: " + text);
        }

        // set up the callback again
        proc.StandardOutput.BaseStream.BeginRead(stdOutBuffer, 0, stdOutBuffer.Length, readStdOut, proc);
    }
```

Any idea how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read from `System.Diagnostics.StandardOutput` (if you use a blocking read you'll have to do it in a separated thread) until you find a match for that string, then display your messagebox and send the character to the `StandardInput` of the process according to the user choice.

---

Quick summary of the things we tried:

- "normal" asynchronous read with `BeginOutputReadLine` -> surely fails because the message from the application isn't terminated with a `'\n'`;
- asynchronous read in 1-byte blocks -> seems to fail because the application isn't flushing the buffer;
- adding a `fflush(stdout)` to the C application + previous approach: success! Apparently the program wasn't flushing the output buffer before the `getch()`.

Interestingly, this probably wouldn't happen in a C++ application using the standard iostreams, since `cin` is tied to `cout`, and before any input operation on `cin` happens `cout` is automatically flushed. I thought it was reasonable that something like this happened also for `stdin`/`stdout`, but I can't seem to find any reference to it into the standard (also the fact chat `getch()` is nonstandard and differs from the other IO functions in being unbuffered may be related).

Fore more info see the comments. :)

Comment: Hi I've tried using another thread, the problem is the same: I could not read the "file exists, overwrite?" output before the worker thread goes to the loop. Added problematic code in question.

Comment: @Dan7: which loop are you referring to? At some moment do you get that `MessageBox` with the output of the program?

Comment: If the file I select is a new file, the `MessageBox` will display all output just fine. But if the file I select will cause the tool to ask overwriting options, no `MessageBox` will show up.

Comment: @Dan: This could be caused by your command line program detecting that its output is being redirected and therefor buffering it. Can you verify that buffering is turned off in your command line program?

Comment: Hm, maybe I got it... the `BeginOutputReadLine` notifies you only after each line is received, but when it asks that question the program do not put a newline (but I think it flushes the buffer automatically before the getch()), so you don't get notified.

Comment: @Gabe: I'm a C++ noob but I assume you use `setvbuf` and `setbuf` to turn off buffering? If so it seems the author didn't turn it off for stdout. @Matteo: It makes sense now. I guess you are right. So I take it at this point there is no way to capture the output, without tinkering with the tool's source? Or I could just replicate the tool's behaviour in C# code and redirect input at appropriate times.

Comment: @Dan7: I think you could get away using asynchronous nonblocking IO to get the data written by the process and compare it with the expected string. Now I'm not on a computer, probably tomorrow I'll add some relevant code to my answer.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I'm not sure if I've done it right, but I used `proc.StandardOutput.BaseStream.BeginRead(stdOutBuffer, 0, stdOutBuffer.Length, readStdOut, proc);` where `readStdOut` is the `AsyncCallback` to read a number of characters at a time. The callback never got called if the tool were to ask the question, but worked fine otherwise -- just like before. I will edit this bit in, if you can look at it that would be great!

Comment: You shouldn't register a callback to be called every n bytes, because it's easy that the string you are looking for won't be exactly n bytes long, thus the program will block waiting for an input and your callback won't be called. I think your best option is polling with a synchronous nonblocking read (sorry about the asynchronous in the last comment, or was a typo).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Hi, even if it reads 1 byte a time, the callback is still never called. How do you do a polling synchronous nonblocking read?

Comment: Hmm, this is strange... What happens if you add a `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf`?

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Yes! I did what you said and finally I could caputre the output! Could you add relevent info from our discussions to the answer for future reference? Anyway thanks a bunch! It felt great to nail down the culprit finally. :)